# Postgresql (Aurora) Sum from jsonb gives odd error

Tags: postgresql, casting, jsonb, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to sum values from a jsonb type column in a table in an Aurora/Postgres database but it doesn't seem to work.

```
select (payload->>'loanAmount')::int from rfqs limit 1;
```

Gives a results of `10000 (int4)`.

```
select sum((payload->>'loanAmount')::int) from rfqs limit 1;
```

Gives a result of: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2000.5"`

It seems like this is something to do with the way the ->> operator converts the json to a string, but it's like something is wrong with that string which prevents it from being correctly typecast to an int.

As a test I did `select SUM(('10000'::int));` which worked fine and returned 10000 as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: cast it as float instead of int, i.e. replace `::int` with `::float`

Comment: Casting as float removes the error but gives an incorrect result... for example if I limit to two rows which are "10000" and "12000" the Summed float results in 9180615.5

Comment: Do you understand that "limit 1" in your "select sum(...) from rfqs"  makes no sense?   You are selecting the sum of all rows, whether you specify "limit 1", "limit 10" or no limit at all.

Comment: @Matt, i think you would benefit from reading more about how aggregate functions and group by works. limit 1 will not limit just 1 row in the sum, the sum will apply over all the rows and then the limit will be applied, since sum is a reducer, you'll always get at most 1 row per group. as there are no groups specified, there is only 1 group.

Comment: Removing the limit statement doesn't change that casting as an integer still gives the same error and casting as a float gives an incorrect value. This seems to work fine in sqlfiddle but not on Aurora so I'm now wondering if it's a weird Aurora issue?

Comment: That because `2000.5` is not an integer. Integers are not allowed to have fractional digits.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to understand  (you will see what the problem is with "::int")

```
select sum(payload->>'loanAmount') from rfqs
```

which is the same as:

```
select sum(payload->>'loanAmount') from rfqs limit 1
```

(An aggregate without group by returns only on row, so "limit 1" is a bit superfluous)

Try

```
SELECT sum(to_number((payload->>'loanAmount'),'999999999D9999')) from rfqs
```

see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9c30a/8

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows I select... I chose 1 just for simplicity. The same thing happens if I choose 2 rows or 9000.

Comment: Of course, that is the meaning of "superfluous".   What do you get from "select sum(payload->>'loanAmount) from rfqs"?

Comment: ```ERROR:  function sum(text) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum(payload->>'loanAmount') from rfqs limit 3;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: the ->> operator on a jsonb column returns a string so it'll need to be typecast somehow... yet casting as integer gives the error stated in the original post, and casting as a float gives a weird huge number that isn't at all the actual sum of the values in question.

Comment: One of the loanAmount must contain a fraction, or is too big for an int.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that, but as far as I'm able to see they don't, and casting as bigint or float still doesn't work. I'm assuming that there is something weird in the way that ->> creates a string which means it isn't a perfectly valid string somehow... but haven't yet found a way to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: select (payload->>'loanAmount') from rfqs where payload->>'loanAmount' like "%2000.5%"  ?

Comment: The queries I originally stated plus the one in your sqlfiddle both work fine on sqlfiddle but fail against an Aurora/Postgres instance. I'm wondering if it's an issue with Aurora vs normal Postgres.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173166/discussion-between-gerard-h-pille-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Some of your "loanAmount" properties does not have integer value. First record does though.

To find offenting records:

```
SELECT payload FROM rfqs WHERE (payload->>'loanAmount') <> trunc(payload->>'loanAmount')
```